# Doctrine annotations try to autoload wrong annotation

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, annotations

I try to use Symfony 2.6/Doctrine 2 on Ubuntu 14.04 with php5.5.9/mysql5.5. But i get very strange error and couldn't find any solution.

I create very simple entity with `doctrine:generate:entity` command. Everything is just fine. But when I try to create table with `doctrine:schema:update` command I get an imposible to fix error :)

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\I" in property AppBundle\Entity\Language::$id does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Well, actually it's right. There is nothing such `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\I`.

It's all about `@ORM\Id`. When I change `@ORM\Id`, the error also changes. I change it to `@ORM\Hello`, the error changes as `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Hello`. But when I change it to `@ORM\Isthisreal`, the error stand still as `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\I`.

I thing there is some parsing error about case sensitiveness. But couldn't find any sollution. I tried lots of things but nothing changes. Here is my simple entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Language
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\LanguageRepository")
 */
class Language
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="iso", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $iso;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getid()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setisActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getisActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set iso
     *
     * @param string $iso
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setiso($iso)
    {
        $this->iso = $iso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get iso
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getiso()
    {
        return $this->iso;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: You can also try to import exactly Id class by `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id` and use `@Id` in annotations.

Comment: Also you can try to place `@ORM\Id` before `@ORM\Column` annotation. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I did all of them but nothing changes :(

Comment: What error produced when you used  `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id` statement with `@Id` annotation?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov  
  
`[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@I" in property AppBundle\Entity\Language::$id was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?`

Comment: Are your file in UTF-8?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Yes, it's UTF-8. I use PhpStorm.  I think this problem is about some PHP config or something like that. But I couldn't find what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78086/discussion-between-michael-sivolobov-and-emreyilmaz7c6).

Answer (score 2):

Try run this before  **doctrine:schema:update**

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: What is the relation between exporting this environment variable and doctrine's schema-tool? Is there an official documentation link about this?